# I want to access a variable declared in filter

Tags: grails, filter, before-filter

```
def filters = {
     forUser(controller:'user', action:'*') {
         before = {
            user=springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()
            log.info("came to filter and the user is" + user)
         }
         after = {

         }
         afterView = {

         }
     }
}
```

I want to access this user variable in the user controller.
Is it possible without making a session variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use request-scope variable:

```
request.setAttribute('user', user)
```

and use it in GSP as:

```
${user}
```

or in controller:

```
request['user']
//or
request.user
```

Comment: I want to use it in the controller User. the variable that I made in filter

Comment: ok, you can use it in the controller (`request.getAttribute('user')`). btw, i don't see any benefits of it, you already can use `springSecurityService.currentUser` in controller

Comment: Thanks,there is a lot of places m using the code. so I thought to put it in the filter.and apart from this there are a lot many other duplication of code too in other controllers. So is it fine if I use filters or if theres some better approach, could you suggest me? I have lately started up with grails

Comment: Using a service seems as more standard way, but you can use filter there, it's not a problem.

Comment: But then how do I set the service to be working as a before or after interceptor? This was why I chose filter

Comment: i mean that you can call `springSecurityService.currentUser` (w/o any before/after) anywhere, instead of filter + `request.user`

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
 params.user = user
```

then you can access it in your controler as

```
 params.user
```

and in your gsp:

```
 ${params.user}
```

Very concise